# Remove all tr and add a new set of tr in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table, there are 20 tr but when i click the button I want the tr to be 4 only.

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   <tr class="data">
   <td>ID</td>
   <td>Item</td>
   </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

My button:

```
<button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filter</button>
```

My Script:

```
$('#btnFilter').on('click', function() {
        $('.data').empty();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        $('.data').append('<td>asd</td>');
    });
```

It is displaying 20 again...

Comment: but you have 20 `tr` with just 2 `td`s in each and wat is `$('.data')`

Comment: I update it. my tr's class is data. Sorry.

Comment: It is completly unclear what you are asking. See Manish's comment...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#btnFilter').on('click', function() {
  $('.table tbody tr:gt(3)').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Item</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filter</button>
```

use [:gt() selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

**NOTE:index starts with 0**

Comment: @A.Wolff i didnt actually realized until you said to see the comment. i think OP needs to clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```js
$(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $('.table').append('<tr class="empty"><td>ID</td><td>Item</td></tr>');
  }

  $('#btnFilter').on('click', function() {
    $('.table').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      $('.table').append('<tr><td>asd</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filter</button>
```